# Why for two binary numbers $x,y$ is $\neg (\neg x + y) = x - y $ true?

Tags: boolean-algebra, binary

Iv'e noticed, empirically, that for two integers  $x$ and $y$ in binary representation (two's complement) it holds that $$\neg (\neg x + y) = x - y $$

Where $\neg$ is the bitwise "not" operation and we discard the overflow bit if it exists. (Say the two numbers are of a fixed width $k$ and so all operations are modulo $2^k$.)

Why does this work? (or am I wrong and there exists a counter example?)

Comment: I'm guessing some form of De Morgan's laws would apply here, together with the definition of subtraction in terms of addition.

Comment: @DonThousand In two's complement, $\neg x +x=-1$

Comment: @saulspatz Correct, my bad. My argument could be modified to hold regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you discard overflow, then for any $x$ you get $\neg x+x+1=11...11+00...01=00...00=0$, 
so $\neg x=-x-1$. Using only this identity, we can find
\begin{align}
\neg(\neg x+y)
&=-(\neg x+y)-1
\\&=-(-x-1+y)-1
\\&=x-y.
\end{align}
For this reason, when your computer needs to calculate $-x$ from $x$, it actually calculates $\neg x+1$. Also, any expression of the form $x-y$ will likely be compiled into $x+\neg y+1$.

To sidetrack even more and relate this to some pure maths just for fun, recall $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=(1-x)^{-1}$ holds for $|x|<1$. Now notice that plugging in $x=2$ the left hand side becomes $\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n$ and the right hand side becomes $-1$. If you write down the partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n$, you get $11...11$. This is not a coincidence :)

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer. Regarding the second paragraph, I'm intrigued, would you care to add a hint?

Comment: I am by no means an expert on this particular topic, but I am fascinated by it as well. What I know is that this is related to $p$-adic numbers and the $p$-adic metric. There is a great video by the amazing channel 3Blue1Brown on YouTube about how one might invent the $p$-adic numbers to interpret this result. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFDM1ip5HdU